# Color a cell text field on excel with kendo ui export

Tags: excel, kendo-ui

I am able to color a number cell with the following code

```
cell.format = '[green]$#,###0'
```

I can't customize a text field though I am using the following format.

```
cell.format = '[green]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to use *cell.color* to set color. Once problem what you can meet is that it not recognize colors as "red", "blue" etc. You have to use hexa entry.

```
row.cells[cellIndex].color = "#582A71";
```

[Dojo example here](http://dojo.telerik.com/AYOMu)

Anyway, I recommend check [this page](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook) there is described what kendo workbook can do. If you meet this syntax

```
rows: [
    { cells: [ { value: "red", color: "#ff0000" } ] }
]
```

then in your export function, you can rewrite it to something like this

```
cell.value = "red";
cell.color = "#ff0000";
```